# mod_expires.c cause session problems

Tags: caching, session-cookies, browser-cache, mod-expires

I active mod_expires.c with this configuration :

```
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType appliction/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
 </IfModule>
 ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

It works very well, everything is catched fine. However, since its active some customer told me they got another account from another customer when they log in. I can't reproduce the bug in my pc login works perfectly fine.

anyone get a clue ? Thanks

Comment: Still having the issue ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of your .htaccess:

```
<filesMatch "\.(php)$">
  ExpiresActive Off
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how the hell a client browser could caching php files ?